# I want to show recently view product in page account Bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

[image]
I want to show recently view product in page account Bigcommerce

Answer (score 1):

This template in cornerstone has the code to show recently viewed products https://github.com/bigcommerce/cornerstone/blob/master/templates/pages/account/recent-items.html

If you want to access the products directly from your own template, you have access to `customer.recently_viewed_products.items`